# Is CloudKit end-to-end encrypted?

Tags: encryption, cloudkit

For our messaging app, if we send user messages directly to [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/) (without doing any of our own encryption), can we claim that our app is [end-to-end encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption), "where only the communicating users can read the messages"?

Comment: At almost **50k rep** you must know that a yes or no question isn't very constructive...

Comment: It is not the cloud, it is the encryption and how the keys are exchanged. It is so deceptively simple and yet there are so few secure implementations, in my estimation it is iMessages and Signal by [Open Whisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/). Now you come along and think you can do as well as [Moxie](https://moxie.org/)?

Comment: If you want a secure system you need to hire a cryptographic domain expert for the design and review of the implementation. That is what I have done for commercial systems in the past and then I slept well at night.

Comment: @zaph Thank you. Does CloudKit handle the encryption for us, so that we don't have to do any encryption? Please see the update question.

Comment: I can't see any way CloudKit security would offer end-to-end encryption. To get an idea of what is involoved in secure end-to-end encryption see Open Whisper Systems [Technical Documentation](https://whispersystems.org/docs/) and [iOS Security 2017](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) iMessage: page 43, CloudKit page 45. For an idea of Apple Cloud security see [Apple Black hat 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLGFriOKz6U&feature=youtu.be) 32:26 to 35:56. End-to-end security is not an easy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

I presume/assume this is a coding question? So I'll answer with a coded answer :)

You can offer your guarantee that messages are only readable by communicating users by encrypting the messages using public/private key pairs. Technology that has been around for more than a while now. This discussion talks in detail about the process.

Search for "Swift RSA Public Key Encryption Howto" on https://forums.developer.apple.com forum.

Comment: Thank you. So, are you saying that CloudKit doesn't do end-to-end encryption for us, ie, we have to do it ourselves? Please see our updated question.

Comment: The problems are key sharing, store and forward storage and perfect forward secrecy for starters. It is really a very complicated and difficult thing to achieve.

Comment: @user3069232 From the forum message cited Quinn “The Eskimo!”  replys: … **Designing your own crypto scheme is something that should only be attempted by crypto experts** (and even they get it wrong most of the time, hence we’re at TLS version 1.2 :-)

Comment: @user3069232 Right off the top this is incorrect, the public key is used for encryption, not the private key. Each could sent the other their public key and encrypt with the others public key, that would be secure … except how do you know you are connecting with the correct entity and there could be a MITM, this brings up the key exchange problem. SSL does not by itself solve this problem.

Comment: Your right. I got that the wrong way round :) the correct sequence; person 1 encrypts their message with person 2's public key. Then only person 2 can decrypt it, since only person 2 has the matching private key. Encryption with the private key is used to prove authenticity. If person 1 encrypts a message with their own private key then person 2 can decrypt it with person 1's public key, which proves that person 1 originated the message since it could only have been encrypted with their private key. I deleted my incorrect comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old and somewhat controversial question, but I thought I'd lend my two cents on the subject.

After some quick Googling, the most authoritative public and user-facing answer to this question I've found is on [Apple's Privacy page](https://www.apple.com/privacy/features/). See the section on iCloud, which reads,

> Your iCloud content [...] is encrypted when it’s transferred and when it’s stored on our servers.

It then talks about CloudKit.

That sounds pretty *end-to-end*-ish to me.

However, they go on to state that "some personal data, such as Home and Health data, is stored with end-to-end encryption." This contrasting passage does not bode well for your *"We're end-to-end encrypted!"* requirement, unless the quote above suffices for your purposes.

For my own present project, it does, as my data isn't necessarily business-class levels of sensitive; I don't need full control over what and how everything is encrypted. My biggest concern is that I, *the developer*, cannot see my users' data. This, CloudKit enforces for me, whereas tools like Firebase do not.

That is all.

Happy Googling!